# Java replace multiple characters in a String with one character

Tags: java, arrays, string

Is it possible to replace multiple characters in a string with one?
I saw some ways to do this with loops, but isnt it possible to do it easier?

For example:

input: /////Hello//this////////is///Java

output: /Hello/this/is/Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String s = "/////Hello//this////////is///Java";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("/+", "/"));
```

Comment: If i want to use the: String sepchar = java.io.File.separator; as the replacement it will give me the error: character to be escaped is missing. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: On my Linux `"/////Hello//this////////is///Java".replaceAll("/+", java.io.File.separator)
` works fine. However this separator is taken from FileSystem implementation that may be different on your system. What character it gives you? And what did you try?

Comment: Ok, you probably use windows and get "\\" as separator character, quickfix is: `java.io.File.separator.replace("\\", "\\\\")` to be used as replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete answer:

```
String Str = new String("Your string");
Set<Character> charsOfString = new HashSet<Character>();
int len = Str.length();
for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    charsOfString.add(Str.charAt(i));
for (Character c : charsOfString) 
    Str = Str.replaceAll(c + "+", c + "");
```

This will delete all duplicated characters of your string